# TypeScript not recognising initialising via a setter

Tags: typescript

In the following example:

```
class Foo {
    private _bar: number;

    constructor(bar: number) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    set bar(bar: number) {
        this._bar = bar;
    }
}
```

TypeScript complains that

> Property '_bar' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

I'd have assumed TypeScript would be intelligent enough to detect that the property is being set via a setter, but apparently not.

I can fix this by changing the assignment in the constructor to set `this._bar` itself, but it's good practice for a class to use its own getters and setters and this fix would be bypassing that. Are there any other ways of resolving this?

Comment: Have you used `this._bar!: number`, instead of `this._bar: number`, this tells TypeScript that you'll define this variable in somewhere other than the constructor, if the variable may or may not be defined, then `this._bar?: number`, would be a better use of syntax.

Answer (score 2):

If the compiler can't figure out that a property is properly initialized, and if you are *sure* that is, you can tell the compiler this via a [definite assignment assertion modifier (`!`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions) on the property declaration:

```
private _bar!: number; // definitely set in constructor, no error now
```

Obviously it would be better if the compiler could verify this for you, but there's little hope of having this happen since the initialization happens inside what amounts to a function/method call, and the compiler basically assumes that such calls don't mutate any state.  This assumption isn't always correct (e.g., it's wrong right now) but it's pragmatic; *fully* analyzing all the side effects of a function/method call would be impossible to implement feasibly (it would be essentially simulating the program being run on all possible inputs), so any analysis would have to be heuristic and necessarily incomplete or unsound.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) for a quite lengthy discussion of the tradeoffs involved.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoaXoAcBOAlgG5gAuAptAPoBGYeAhAFzQB2ArgLY3l4Dc0APSDoAE3IAzAqwIUQAT2gRypaNOjB4rCKTztgpeHgwZsGrTr0GjACjp4WHbrwCUKU2eykAFgQgA6e2gAXmh7Pg8sAF8TTGxlVXs7ekcuHjw3NDjPaB8-f1p6ELD6COzoGPRKoA)